# $nP(|X|>n)\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, show $\frac{2}{n}\int_{0}^nxP(|X|>x)dx\to0$

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory

If we have $nP(|X|>n)\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Can we show that $\frac{2}{n}\int_{0}^nxP(|X|>x)dx\to0$ as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: The convergence $nP(|X_n| > x) \overset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$ holds for which $x$?

Comment: Sorry, there were some typos, I have corrected them

Comment: You should clearly state all the conditions. What is $X_1$ ? Are we given a sequence of random variables $(X_n)$? If we just consider one random variable only, why not using the symbol $X$ ?

Comment: yes you are right, It's better to use $X$ instead of$X_1$.

Comment: Any integrability condition ?

Comment: No there isn't it's just Riemann integrate

Comment: I mean the integrability of the random variable $X$. By definition, a random variable is just a measurable function $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, which needs not be integrable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that $$xP(|X| > x) \leq (\lfloor x\rfloor + 1)P(|X| > \lfloor x\rfloor) = \lfloor x\rfloor P(|X| > \lfloor x\rfloor) + P(|X| > \lfloor x\rfloor)$$
which is the sum of two terms that each go to $0$ as $x\to \infty$, hence $xP(|X| > x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$.  Then there is some $N$ such that $x > N$ implies $xP(|X| > x) < \epsilon$, so let $n > N$ and write
$$\begin{align*}\frac{2}{n} \int_0^n xP(|X| > x)\,dx &= \frac{2}{n} \int_0^N xP(|X| > x)\,dx + \frac{2}{n} \int_N^n xP(|X| > x)\,dx \\ & \leq \frac{2}{n}\int_0^N xP(|X|>x)\,dx + \frac{2}{n}\int_N^n\epsilon\,dx \\ &\leq \frac{2}{n}\int_0^N xP(|X|>x)\,dx + 2\epsilon\end{align*}$$

Let $n\to \infty$ to see $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{2}{n}\int_0^n xP(|X|>x)\,dx \leq 2\epsilon$$
and since $\epsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{2}{n}\int_0^n xP(|X|>x) \,dx = 0$.

Finish by noting that $\frac{2}{n}\int_0^n xP(|X|>x)\,dx \geq 0$.